# Opencv(Python) memory usage issue

Tags: python, xml, opencv, memory

I've a problem  with my software in Python. It's a big while cicle where I took a intel realsense (USB camera) stream. Using opencv I make a couple of findContours and I send the results of contours to another software.

The problem is that there is a memory consuption. In fact the RAM usage increase every 2-3 seconds by 0.1%.

II don't know what to do...

This is the code (sorry if it's not beautifull but I'm testing a lot of things)

```
import numpy as np
import random
import socket
import cv2
import time
import math
import pickle
import httplib, urllib
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

try:
    import pyrealsense as pyrs
except:
    print("No pyralsense Module installed!")
#funzione per registrare gli eventi del mouse
def drawArea(event,x,y, flag, param):
    global fx,fy,ix,iy

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ix,iy = x,y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        fx,fy = x,y

def RepresentsInt(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

quit = False
read = False
while read == False:
        file = open('default.xml', 'r')
        tree = ET.parse(file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for child in root:
            if child.tag == "intel":
                intel = int(child[0].text)
            elif child.tag == "output":
                portOut = int(child[2].text)
            elif child.tag =="source":
                video_source = child.text
        file.close()
        root.clear()
        ix,iy = -1,-1
        fx,fy = -1,-1
        timeNP = 10
        last = time.time()
        smoothing = 0.9
        fps_smooth = 30


        #video_source = video_source.split(",")
        read = True

if RepresentsInt(video_source):
    video_source = int(video_source)

if intel == 1:
    pyrs.start()
    dev = pyrs.Device(video_source)
master = 1
address = ('', 3333)
broadSockListe = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
broadSockListe.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
broadSockListe.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
broadSockListe.bind(('',3333))
while True:
    if master == 0:
        datas, address = broadSockListe.recvfrom(1024)

        if str(datas) == "8000":
            separator = ":"
            seq = (address[0],"8081")
            masterAddr = separator.join(seq)
            IP = str([l for l in (
            [ip for ip in socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] if not ip.startswith("127.")][:1], [
                [(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in
                 [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]]) if l][0][0])
            params = separator.join(("addUnit",IP,str(portOut),"camera","generalList.xml"))
            params = urllib.urlencode({"Python":params})
            headers = {}
            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(masterAddr)
            conn.request("POST",masterAddr ,params, headers)
            params = separator.join(("masterIP",address[0],str(portOut)+"/","default.xml"))
            params = urllib.urlencode({"Python":params})
            headers = {}
            myip = IP + ":8081"
            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(myip)
            #eseguo una post al mio server
            conn.request("POST", myip, params, headers)
            broadSockListe.close()
            #imposto master a 1 per dire che l'ho registrato e posso partire col programma
            master = 1
    read = False
    while read == False:

            '''# leggo le varie impostazioni dal file default
            file = open('default.xml','r+')
            tree = ET.parse(file)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for child in root:
                if child.tag == "modifica" and child.text == "1":
                    child.text = "0"
                    tree.write('default.xml')
            root.clear()
            file.close()'''
            read = True


    prev,prevprev,dirX,dirY = 0,0,0,0
    spostamento = 15
    UDP_IP = ["", ""]
    UDP_PORT = ["", ""]
    UDP_IP[0] = "127.0.0.1"
    UDP_PORT[0] = 3030
    IP_left = "127.0.0.1"
    IP_right = "127.0.0.1"
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("",portOut))
    message = ""
    sep = "-"
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
    #rettangoli = [x,y,width,height,angle,box, area, contours]
    rettangoli = []
    cnt = 0
    letto = 0
    while True:
        now = time.time()
        if letto < now - 2 or letto == 0 or now < letto:
            letto = now
            print(now)
            read = False
            while read == False:
                    file = open('default.xml', 'r')
                    tree = ET.parse(file)
                    root = tree.getroot()
                    for child in root:
                        if child.tag == "output":
                            UDP_IP[1] = child[0].text
                            UDP_PORT[1] = int(child[1].text)
                        if child.tag == "effects":
                            erode = int(child[0].text)
                            erodePos = int(child[1].text)
                            erode2 = int(child[2].text)
                            erodePos2 = int(child[3].text)
                            dilate1 = int(child[4].text)
                            dilatePos1= int(child[5].text)
                            dilate2 = int(child[6].text)
                            dilatePos2 = int(child[7].text)
                            blur = int(child[8].text)
                            blurPos = int(child[9].text)
                        if child.tag == "intel":
                            val1Min = int(child[1].text)
                            val1Max = int(child[2].text)
                            val2Min = int(child[3].text)
                            val2Max = int(child[4].text)
                            val3Min = int(child[5].text)
                            val3Max = int(child[6].text)
                        if child.tag == "modifica":
                            if child.text == "1":
                                break
                        #definisco dimensioni per collisioni
                        if child.tag == "size":
                            blobSize= int(child[0].text)
                            dimBordoBlob= int(child[1].text)
                        if child.tag == "visualizza":
                            visualizza= child.text
                        if child.tag == "feedback":
                            SFB = int(child.text)
                    root.clear()
                    file.close()
                    read = True
        dev.wait_for_frame()
        c = dev.colour
        c = cv2.cvtColor(c, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        d = dev.depth * dev.depth_scale * -60
        d = d[5:485, 25:635]
        d = cv2.applyColorMap(d.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLORMAP_HSV)
        c = cv2.resize(c, (320 ,240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        d = cv2.resize(d, (320,240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        #trasformo i colori in HSV per filtrarli
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(d, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        lower_red = np.array([val1Min, val2Min, val3Min])
        upper_red = np.array([val1Max, val2Max, val3Max])
        frame = cv2.inRange(frame, lower_red, upper_red)
        dimensions = frame.shape
        widthStream = dimensions[1]
        heightStream = dimensions[0]
        roomFrame = np.zeros(( heightStream,widthStream, 3), np.uint8)
        roomFrame[:] = (0, 0, 0)
        fgmask = frame
        halfheight = int(heightStream / 2)
        halfwidth = int(widthStream / 2)
        for i in range(0, 15):
            if erode >= 1 and erodePos == i:
                fgmask = cv2.erode(fgmask, kernel, iterations=erode)
            if dilate1 >= 1 and dilatePos1 == i:
                fgmask = cv2.dilate(fgmask, kernel, iterations=dilate1)
            if erode2 >= 1 and erodePos2 == i:
                fgmask = cv2.erode(fgmask, kernel, iterations=erode2)
            if dilate2 >= 1 and dilatePos2 == i:
                fgmask = cv2.dilate(fgmask, kernel, iterations=dilate2)
            if blur == 1 and blurPos == 1:
                fgmask = cv2.GaussianBlur(fgmask, (5, 5), 0)
        if ix > fx:
            temp = fx
            fx = ix
            ix = temp
        if iy > fy:
            temp = fy
            fy = iy
            iy = temp
        if cnt == 0:
            ix,iy = 1,1
            fx,fy = widthStream-1,heightStream-1
        fgmask, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        rettangoli = []
        for cont in contours:
            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cont)
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            box = np.int0(box)
            width = rect[1][0]
            height = rect[1][1]
            angle = rect[2]
            if width > height:
                angle = 180 + angle
            else:
                angle = 270 + angle
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
            centerX = int(w / 2 + x)
            centerY = int(h / 2 + y)
            M = cv2.moments(cont)
            area = int(M['m00'])
            if area > blobSize:
                if ix < centerX < fx and iy < centerY < fy:
                    cv2.drawContours(fgmask, [cont], 0, (100, 100, 100), dimBordoBlob)
                    cv2.drawContours(fgmask, [cont], 0, (255, 255, 255), -1)
                    rettangoli.append([centerX, centerY, w, h, angle, box, area, cont])
        indice = 0
        fgmask, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS)
        if intel == 1:
            fgmask = cv2.cvtColor(fgmask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
        rettangoli = []
        for cont in contours:
            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cont)
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            box = np.int0(box)
            width = rect[1][0]
            height = rect[1][1]
            angle = rect[2]
            if width > height:
                angle = 180 + angle
            else:
                angle = 270 + angle
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
            centerX = int(w / 2 + x)
            centerY = int(h / 2 + y)
            M = cv2.moments(cont)
            indice += 1
            if M['m00'] > blobSize:
                if ix < centerX < fx and iy < centerY < fy:
                    rettangoli.append([centerX, centerY, w, h, angle, box, int(M['m00']), cont])
                    cv2.drawContours(roomFrame, [cont], 0, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        for rett in rettangoli:
            seq = (message,np.array_str(rett[7]))
            message = sep.join(seq)
        temp = 0
        while temp < len(UDP_IP):
            sock.sendto(bytes(message), (UDP_IP[temp], UDP_PORT[temp]))
            temp += 1
        message = ""
        if SFB == 1:
            cv2.imshow("Camera Intel", roomFrame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('r'):
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            quit = True
            break
        name = "color.jpeg"
        cv2.imwrite(name, c)
        name = "bn.jpeg"
        cv2.imwrite(name, roomFrame)
    if intel == 0:
        cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new objects in your while loop. Take now for example, you create a variable and then you assign a new object to it that only lives in that loop. If you declare the variables before your loop the same object will be overwritten instead of re-created.

By just declaring the variables ahead of time with `name = None` you will be able to make sure you reuse these variables.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi, thansk for the answer. So you are saying that I should declare all variables outside the while? Have I understood?

I',ll try...

Comment: Any variables you want to not create a new instance of but just overwrite the old one, yes. Python does all the memory management for you but you do have to give it something to work with. Typically variables will live inside of the loop only, but by never leaving the loop I can imagine they are not properly discarded.
If you debug your code in something like intellij you can also see what objects are in memory, this will help you find the culprit as well.